# Spring Boot get local storage from Angular Request (Error in Controller - 500)

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, local-storage, session-storage

i dont know how use the local storage in Spring boot, my front end is in Angular and i have to send the Local Storage in a controller that convert in DTO to get rows from database ext ext, actually the browser return me error 500

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public ..
```

The request from Angular

```
getAttestazioni(): Observable<Posts[]> {
    return this.http.post<Posts[]>(this.myAppUrl + this.myApiPostsUrl, this.authService.getLoggedUserFromSessionStorage())
      .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.errorHandler)
      );
  }
```

Function to get the local storage.

```
 public getLoggedUserFromSessionStorage(): User {
    if (localStorage) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    }
    return null;
  }
```

The Controller of Spring Boot

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/posts", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public ResponseEntity<List<PostDTO>> fetchAll(@RequestBody UserDTO currentUser) {
        List<Post> posts;
        List<PostDTO> postsDTO = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            posts = postService.getAll(currentUser);
            if (posts != null) {
                postsDTO = postService.fromVOtoDTO(posts, postsDTO);
            }
            if (postsDTO.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("No Posts found");
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(attestazioniDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

This is my Local Storage, the object is in body:, and maybe for this there isnt the map in the controller.

```
{headers: {normalizedNames: {}, lazyUpdate: null}, status: 200, statusText: "OK",…}
body: {idUser: "232323", currentGroup: "1213", ip: "192.168.1.2",…}
headers: {normalizedNames: {}, lazyUpdate: null}
ok: true
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: 4
url: "http://localhost:8080/api/login/"
```

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed changing this

```
 sessionUser = (res as unknown as User);
```

to

```
 sessionUser = (res.body as unknown as User);
```

Now local storage save only the object body .